# Is there a way to get the users of an IRC channel without joining it?

Tags: irc

I want to be able to get the list of users and their details from an IRC channel without joining it and thus increasing its user count.

So instead of issuing `JOIN #chan` and then `NAMES #chan` to get the list of users, I can run the latter command. Is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can issue `NAMES` for a channel where you are not in, but `NAMES` does not display users that are invisible (usermode `+i`).

Most servers set the usermode +i on connect, and some don't even allow changing it.

So if you don't have everyone set their usermode `-i`, you can't see them when not in the channel.

The RFC is not very specific about usermode `+i`. Some say that you can see users with `+i` on a `NAMES` reply if you share a common channel, and others say that you can not.

Answer (score 6):

While [the RFC implies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-4.2.5) that you *should* be able to issue `/NAMES #chan` from outside `#chan` (or even just issue `/NAMES` to get everybody), in practice many servers I've seen will ignore the former if you are not in a channel and just reject the latter.

The only reliable way is to issue `/JOIN` and `/NAMES`, and then deduct one from the user list to account for your bot.

Answer (score 4):

You can see the number of users with `/list #channel`

Comment: That wasn't the question - *"get the list of users and their details"*.

Comment: The count was about getting the information without affecting the IRC channel (by joining to get the information).